# Do you know of a good F# and C# interop example available?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, f#, backgroundworker

I am going to write a C# WinForms application which will run a long data-crunching task in a BackgroundWorker, show progress in a ProgressBar and have buttons to start, pause, resume and cancel the operation. I'd like to write the calculation in F#. Do you know of any good examples or readings available in the Web which can help me?

Answer (score 4):

[Luke Hoban](http://blogs.msdn.com/lukeh/) in F# team has a [video](http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/FT20) at PDC 2009. There is a concurrent image downloader using asynchronous programming, which does not block GUI thread. This example also illustrates how to use C#(GUI) to call F# module(the image downloader).

The example is at the second half of the video.

Answer (score 2):

You might also find [this article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/Programming-user-interfaces-using-f-sharp-workflows.aspx) helpful.

---

Edit: I realize the article I'm pointing at is all F# (not really using interop) but it does demonstrate parallel programming with F# so it does seem appropriate to the question.